# SELECT MAX() too slow - any alternatives?

Tags: sql, sql-server, timeout, max

I've inherited a SQL Server based application and it has a stored procedure that contains the following, but it hits timeout. I believe I've isolated the issue to the SELECT MAX() part, but I can't figure out how to use alternatives, such as ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY...

Anyone got any ideas?

### Here's the "offending" code:

```
SELECT BData.*, B.* 
FROM BData
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX( BData.StatusTime ) AS MaxDate, BData.BID
    FROM BData
    GROUP BY BData.BID
) qryMaxDates
ON ( BData.BID = qryMaxDates.BID ) AND ( BData.StatusTime = qryMaxDates.MaxDate )
INNER JOIN BItems B ON B.InternalID = qryMaxDates.BID
WHERE  B.ICID = 2
ORDER BY BData.StatusTime DESC;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How slow? How large is your table?

Comment: What are you trying to retrieve? The last changed BData entry for a specific B.ICID? What is the execution plan of the query? Do you have the required indexes?

Comment: @Emmad: The table has over 14M records and the query fails after 45s

Comment: @Panagiotis: I believe it's trying to obtain the most recent record in BData for each record in BItems. I added indexes for BData.BID, BData.StatusTime, BItems.BID and BItems.ICID. How do I find the execution plan (sorry, I'm a novice at SQL Server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UNSOLVED] But I've moved on!

Thanks to everyone who provided answers / suggestions. Unfortunately I couldn't get any further with this, so have given-up trying for now.

It looks like the best solution is to re-write the application to UPDATE the latest data into into a different table, that way it's a really quick and simple SELECT to latest readings.

Thanks again for the suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

SQL performance problems are seldom addressed by rewriting the query. The compiler already know how to rewrite it anyway. The problem is always indexing. To get `MAX(StatusTime ) ... GROUP BY BID` efficiently, you need an index on `BData(BID, StatusTime)`. For efficient seek of `WHERE  B.ICID = 2` you need an index on `BItems.ICID`.

The query could also be, probably, expressed as a correlated [APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), because it seems that what is what's really desired:

```
SELECT D.*, B.* 
FROM BItems B
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP(1) *
    FROM BData
    WHERE B.InternalID = BData.BID
    ORDER BY StatusTime DESC
) AS D
WHERE  B.ICID = 2
ORDER BY D.StatusTime DESC;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/26c9d/1).

This is not semantically the same query as OP, the OP would return multiple rows on StatusTime collision, I just have a guess though that this is what is desired ('the most recent BData for this BItem').

Comment: Thanks for this code. Unfortunately I get the following error when I run it: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.

Comment: @user3061406 I fixed the query, see the linked SQL Fiddle

Comment: Perhaps, to make it (more) equal to the OP's semantically, one could use `TOP (1) WITH TIES` in the CROSS APPLY.

Comment: @AndriyM: absolutely. I didn't thought about that solution, but you're absolutely right.

Comment: This answer (or a simple variant of it) did indeed speed things up for me, while retaining accuracy.  Syntax changes to your code may be required.

Answer (score 6):

Consider creating the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX LatestTime ON dbo.BData(BID, StatusTime DESC);
```

This will support a query with a CTE such as:

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BID ORDER BY StatusDate DESC)
  FROM dbo.BData
)
SELECT * FROM x 
INNER JOIN dbo.BItems AS bi
  ON x.BID = bi.InternalID
WHERE x.rn = 1 AND bi.ICID = 2
ORDER BY x.StatusDate DESC;
```

Whether the query still gets efficiencies from any indexes on `BItems` is another issue, but this should at least make the aggregate a simpler operation (though it will still require a lookup to get the rest of the columns).

Another idea would be to stop using `SELECT *` from both tables and only select the columns you actually need. If you really need all of the columns from both tables (this is rare, especially with a join), then you'll want to have covering indexes on both sides to prevent lookups.

I also suggest calling any identifier the same thing throughout the model. Why is the ID that links these tables called `BID` in one table and `InternalID` in another?

Also please always reference tables using their schema.

- [Bad habits to kick : avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)

Comment: Yeah, normally using * would be bad, but in this instance we're displaying a table with all the data :(  I added your index and ran your SQL (modified the "StatusDates" to be "StatusTime", but I then get the following error: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'dbo.BD.BDID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Any ideas?

Comment: I agree about using consistent identifiers ;)

Comment: @user3061406 Yep, sorry, I grabbed your subquery and didn't modify it enough. See update.

Answer (score 5):

This may be a late response, but I recently ran into the same performance issue where a simple query involving max() is taking more than 1 hour to execute.

After looking at the execution plan, it seems in order to perform the max() function, every record meeting the where clause condition will be fetched.  In your case, it's every record in your table will need to be fetched before performing max() function.  Also, indexing the BData.StatusTime will not speed up the query.  Indexing is useful for looking up a particular record, but it will not help performing comparison.

In my case, I didn't have the group by so all I did was using the ORDER BY DESC clause and SELECT TOP 1.  The query went from over 1 hour down to under 5 minutes.  Perhaps, you can do what Gordon Linoff suggested and use PARTITION BY.  Hopefully, your query can speed up.

Cheers!

Comment: ORDER BY DESC Faster very much! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following is the version of your query using `row_number()`:

```
SELECT bd.*, b.* 
FROM (select bd.*, row_number() over (partition by bid order by statustime desc) as seqnum
      from BData bd
     ) bd INNER JOIN
     BItems b
     ON b.InternalID = bd.BID and bd.seqnum = 1
WHERE B.ICID = 2
ORDER BY BData.StatusTime DESC;
```

If this is not faster, then it would be useful to see the query plans for your query and this query to figure out how to optimize them.

Answer (score 1):

Depends entirely on what kind of data you have there. One alternative that may be faster is using CROSS APPLY instead of the MAX subquery. But more than likely it won't yield any faster results.

The best option would probably be to add an index on BID, with INCLUDE containing the StatusTime, and if possible filtering that by InternalID's matching BItems.ICID = 2.